# R missing date calculation

Tags: r, date, data.table, data-manipulation

I have `data`:

```
Purshased_Date  value     Refund_Date   MONTH  YEAR   MDY         INTNX
2015-08-14      0         2015-08-14    8      2015   2015-08-01  2015-08-31
2015-08-14      96        NA            8      2015   2015-08-01  2015-08-31
2015-08-14      127       NA            8      2015   2015-08-01  2015-08-31
```

I want to create a new column by calculating above data.
The code is:

```
library(data.table)
data[, NewCol := value * pmax(0, difftime(pmin(Refund_Date, INTNX), pmax(Purshased_Date, MDY-1), units = 'day')) / as.numeric(difftime(INTNX, MDY-1, units = 'day'))]
```

However, R considers `pmin(Refund_Date1, INTNX) = NA` when `Refund_Date = NA`.
I don't want to use `NA`.
What I want is when `Refund_Date = NA`, `pmin(Refund_Date, INTNX) = INTNX`
The result I want looks like following:

```
Purshased_Date  value     Refund_Date   MONTH  YEAR   MDY         INTNX         NewCol
2015-08-14      0         2015-08-14    8      2015   2015-08-01  2015-08-31    0
2015-08-14      96        NA            8      2015   2015-08-01  2015-08-31    52.64516129
2015-08-14      127       NA            8      2015   2015-08-01  2015-08-31    69.64516129
```

How can I do? Any suggestion?

Comment: `pmin(..., na.rm = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Great. It works. Maybe u can add to answer and I will mark it.